# How to observe `URLSearchParams` changes

Tags: javascript

When I change `new URL().searchParams`, changes will be synchronized to the `URL` object. But `URLSearchParams` doesn't seem to provide a way to listen its changes.

I checked the [`url`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v20.3.0/lib/internal/url.js#L272) source code of nodejs, it uses a private `#context` to apply changes to `URL` object, I can't do the same thing.

The only way I can think of is to use a `Proxy` to intercept its `set` and `apply` operations, Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "listen its changes"? Could you post some code to illustrate what you are trying to do?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Why do you need to react to this change when it happens? If you need to do some checks against the value, do it when you're going to use it. Also, note that even your `Proxy` idea wouldn't work just like that. If someone sets the `.search` property of the `URL` object, it will change the associated `URLSearchParams` object too, without calling any setter/method of that `URLSearchParams` object.